# Geometric Multiplicity, Eigenspace of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is an $r$ x $s$ matrix and B is an $s$ x $r$ matrix.

$E_\mu(C)$ is the eigenspace of square matrix C with eigenvalue $\mu ≠ 0$.

Proof:

> $dimE_\mu(AB) = dimE_\mu(BA)$

I imagine one would need to find the basis of eigenvectors for both spaces, but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $v$ is an eigenvector for $AB$, then $Bv$ is an  ...

Comment: Eigenvector of $BA$. Does that imply that the spaces have the same number of eigenvectors?

Comment: I still don't understand... sigh

Comment: You have an invertible linear map taking the eigenspace for one onto the eigenspace for the other.  Such maps take a basis to a basis, and thus preserve dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to look at it. Let $\mu \neq 0$. By the standard argument (mentioned in Robert Israel's answer), we have well-defined linear maps $T : E_\mu(AB) \to E_\mu(BA)$, $x \mapsto Bx$ and $S : E_\mu(BA) \to E_\mu(AB)$, $y \mapsto Ay$. Note that $T$ and $S$ are almost each other's inverse:
\begin{align*}
STx &= ABx = \mu x;\\[1ex]
TSy &= BAy = \mu y.
\end{align*}
Therefore $T$ (resp. $S$) is an isomorphism with inverse $T^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mu} S$ (resp. $S^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mu} T$). Since $E_\mu(AB)$ and $E_\mu(BA)$ are isomorphic, they have the same dimension.